# Any way to set up an activity History fro ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, rails-admin

I'm looking at RailsAdmin and noticed that it has an activity history i.e a note of all actions committed on the application. I'm looking for a really quick way to integrate such a feature on a project that is based using activeadmin. Any ideas on how it can be done though or what gems can I use out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem and came across this page in the active_admin wiki:

[Auditing via paper trail](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Auditing-via-paper_trail-%28change-history%29)

I haven't tried it yet (and you may no longer need the answer) but I figured I would post it here anyway since others might find it useful.